# Класс с переменными

Tags: c++

Если глобальных переменных достаточно много, имеет ли смысл объединять их в отдельный класс?

Я считаю, что это бред, ибо чтобы изменить переменную нужно писать что-то типа var.result++ и так с каждой переменной. Ошибочно ли моё мнение?

```
UPD:
```

Понятно, что в случае с 200+ переменных нужно использовать классы, но что насчёт такого количества глобальных переменных?

```
int threadCount = 4;
bool bShowDebug = true;

string path;
fs::directory_iterator it;

vector<boost::thread> threads;
mutex m;

atomic<long long> result(0);
bool bHaveFiles = false;

void f1();
string f2();
bool f3();
```

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-2a-why-global-variables-are-evil/

Comment: "чтобы изменить переменную нужно писать что-то типа var.result++ " ... Уточните, в чем разница между глобальными переменными и переменными в глобальном классе на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Если у Вас очень много глобальных переменных, то это говорит о том, что пора делать разделение - переменные нужно сгруппировать по назначению. И вот их нужно выделить в отдельные классы (или namespace). А там выясниться, что некоторые функции можно также перенести в эти классы, так как они работают только с заданным набором "переменных".

Comment: @Kromster В том то и дело, что я прошу объяснить что это и зачем нужно. Я представляю это как "тупо перенести все глобальные переменные, объявленные в начале кода в класс"

Comment: @Виталий  Лучше не объявлять много глобальных переменных. Если их объединять, то можно либо поместить их в отдельное пространство имен, чтобы не было коллизий имен или если существуют логические связи между переменными, то поместить их в классы как статические члены класса.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Можно пример?

Comment: Мне представляется, что все изменения переменных должны выполняться функциями-членами класса (иначе зачем инкапсуляция), в которых нет необходимости указывать имя объекта.

Comment: Для начала неплохо бы дать осмысленные имена переменным.

Comment: Без контекста невозможно понять, как именно можно было бы облагородить ваши переменные.

Comment: Хорошо, исправил

Comment: Есть такое подозрение, что вы строите пул потоков и как-то ими обрабрабатываете файловую систему. Почему бы не объединить это все в класс-сервис? Не вижу здесь _переменных_, которые должны быть видны снаружи (суть глобальных переменных - делать их данные доступными и изменяемыми отовсюду). threadCount и bShowDebug видимо могли бы быть константами. И почему первая не имеет префикса, а у второй он есть?

Comment: К примеру, `thread_count` не имеет смысла в качестве глобальной переменной, её может обновлять кто угодно и когда угодно, а может и не обновлять. Если же сделать её приватной статической переменной какого-нибудь базового класса для ваших потоков (либо приватной переменной менеджера потоков), то появится класс ответственный за её актуальность. **Ответственность!** Вот что важно.

Comment: @free_ze да, именно так. Суть понял, буду экспериментировать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 7):

Глобальные переменные и прочие синглтоны - это плохо, по понятным причинам: когда их сотни по разным частям программы, то их сложно отслеживать и очень легко поломать, используя неверно.

Проблема первая: представьте, вы - новый человек в проекте, хотите найти какой-то параметр, назначение которого вам понятно и его существование очевидно, но точное имя неизвестно. Напомню, их сотни по всему проекту. Как вы это будуте делать? Не говоря уже о том, что у похожих логических объектов наверняка будут переменные с похожими именами. Для решения этой проблемы их кластеризуют в пространства имен и делают статическими полями классов. Аналогично тому, как файлы группируют по папкам.

Проблема вторая: есть соблазн менять данные (переменные) напрямую, в обход сложностей бизнес-логики. Так очень легко сломать логическую целостность данных, а ошибка эта может всплыть через время в случайном месте и ее источник определить будет ОЧЕНЬ проблематично. Для решения этой проблемы используется основное свойство парадигмы ООП - инкапсуляция. Переменные классов должны быть приватными, наружу выставляются методы set/get.

И косвенная проблема №3: глобальные переменные "прибивают гвоздями" части программы между собой так, что невозможно независимо тестировать ее отдельные части, т.к. придется воспроизводить очень уж большие куски окружения. После этого любое изменение в бизнес-логике грозит "эффектом бабочки", которое может отозваться эхом там, где вы и не подозревали. Для решения этой проблемы создается абстракция от зависимых данных (в виде интерфейсов или абстрактных классов), которая внедряется извне и легко может быть подменена тестовой "пустышкой" (Mock object).

З.Ы. В сравнении с этими проблемами, необходимость писать имя класса для доступа к переменной - это ерунда.